# Fullscreen VideoView button

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview, mediacontroller, android-fullscreen

I'm currently using a VideoView together with MediaController and I wonder if there is a simple way to add a fullscreen button mode.

That would be a button, on the MediaController bar or somewhere else on the top of the VideoView, that on click, would display the video on a full screen mode.

(Btw, I am very amazed that Android did not add this as a default controller on the MediaController!!!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I removed the `VideoView` from its parent and set it at the content view.

Here as a basic idea (could contain small errors):

```
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(...);
((ViewGroup)video.getParent()).removeChild(video);
setContentView(video);
```

By the way depending on your target platform I would suggest to use the [`TextureView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).